# MediaPlayer stops playing when button is clicked

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I have made an app that is a game. I want a song to play only during main gameplay. I have the MediaPlayer start in the game activity. Then within the fragment for the game, whenever a button is clicked, the song stops. I want the music to keep playing even when the button is clicked.

Game activity:

```
@Override
protected Fragment createFragment() {
    return GameFragment.newInstance();
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.fragment_game, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle item selection
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.quit:
            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
            builder.setCancelable(false);
            builder.setMessage("Are you sure you want to quit this game?");
            builder.setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    finish();
                }
            });
            builder.setNegativeButton("No",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    dialog.cancel();
                }
            });
            AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
            alert.show();
            return true;
        case R.id.music_switch:
            MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.music);
            if (mp.isPlaying())
                mp.stop();
            else
                mp.start();
            return true;
        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

Is there something in the fragment's onClickListener I have to put in?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried commenting out the `mp.stop()` line?

```
if (mp.isPlaying())
    mp.stop(); // <--- here
else
    mp.start();
return true;
```

Comment: Yes, I think the issue is, when the fragment is interacted with, the activity is interrupted

Answer (score 0):

If you check the state and it's playing, you can call the pause command. Please totally refer to this state diagram when using that class because it makes everything way easier. You will notice that from stopped there's not a path back to start. Rather you need to prepare() then start().

[image]